# Change keyboard layout while entering start-up password

Tags: windows-7, login, keyboard-layout, dvorak

I installed Windows 7 with the QWERTY keyboard layout, but have recently started using DVORAK layout so I changed it from Control Panel -> Regional and Language Settings and it set DVORAK to default keyboard layout.

Recently I added a password to log into the administrator account, the problem is that this password field is set to the QWERTY keyboard layout. When I log into Windows the keyboard layout switches back to DVORAK. How can I set the password field on the log in screen to use the DVORAK layout

Comment: While this doesn't directly solve the problem, if Dvorak is selected as the default keyboard layout during your Windows installation, it will default to that on the welcome screen.

Comment: well i started the question saying that I installed windows using qwerty and hence the problem.. fortunately I searched every tab on the regional and language settings and got the solution to the problem

Comment: @EmoryBell imagine that you create a new keyboard layout because you need the tilde to be a dead key (etc)... one can't make this special layout the default when installing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Found the solution:** For future reference if you want to change your keyboard layout on the welcome screen and other accounts on your computer you have to copy the settings to them.

You can do that by navigating to:

*Control Panel -> Regional and Language Settings -> Administerative -> Copy Settings -> Click the check marks (at the bottom) to the welcome screen and accounts that you want to copy the settings to and click ok*

[image]

Comment: In Windows 10, I found this screen by going to Control Panel -> Clock and Region -> Change date, time, or number formats -> Administrative -> Copy Settings

Answer (score 1):

On the Welcome screen, click the Keyboard layout button , and then select a keyboard layout.

Comment: I don't have any. Perhaps because I only have a single keyboard layout? I'm not sure. Regardless, using the `alt`+`right-shift` shortcut to change layout does not change to my account-defined layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you are locked out of windows due to a keyboard layout change follow [these steps](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/change-your-forgotten-windows-password-with-the-linux-system-rescue-cd) to use a liveCD to remove the user password.

NOTE: remove the password, do not reset it. Change it AFTERWARD in Windows proper.